# is it possible to retrieve only non-zero element datas from csc matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im in a situation where I have a matrix data with Compressed Sparse Column(csc) format.

The datas looks like below.

```
(17, 1)     1.0
(18, 2)     1.0
(19, 3)     1.0
(20, 4)     1.0
(91, 5)     1.0
```

the shape of this matrix is `200*200` but all I want from this data is tuple of the column and row data. (i.e. (17, 1), (18, 2),...)

And I want to store them in list.  So the output should be looks like below.

```
[(17, 1), (18, 2), (19, 3), (20, 4), (91, 5)]
```

So, I tried to retrieve the tuple representation of csc matrix but I have no idea how to implement that. Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: Is that a text file?

Comment: @DaniMesejo im afraid its not. its a csc matrix data, and I don't have a .txt data that stores them.

Comment: This doesn't look anything like CSC - it looks like COO.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm sure its csc

Comment: How is your data currently stored? (Don't just say CSC.) Is it serialized in a file somewhere? Is it in a SciPy sparse matrix object, or some other type?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica it is stored in scipy sparse.csc_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` (or any other SciPy sparse matrix type), you can convert it to COO format with `tocoo`, then retrieve the `row` and `col` index arrays:

```
ascoo = yourmatrix.tocoo()
row, col = ascoo.row, ascoo.col
```

These give the row and column indices respectively of the nonzero elements. (Strictly speaking, it gives the row and column indices of the *explicitly represented* elements, so stuff like explicit zeros or duplicate elements will show up here. Also, the arrays may alias arrays underlying the original matrix.)

If you want a list of tuples, you can get that:

```
index_tuples = list(zip(row.tolist(), col.tolist()))
```

(The `tolist` calls ensure that we have ordinary Python scalars instead of NumPy scalar types in the result.)